# Wordpress Category Template Question

Tags: wordpress, templates

I am looking at using a custom template for a set of categories. Is it possible to use a category template (like category-4.php) on a parent category and have the children use that template as well?

So based on the answer so far, is there a way to accomplish this? I want to add text and images to all categories within a parent category.

Comment: maybe this one is usefull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119961/make-all-wordpress-categories-use-their-parent-category-template?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation it does not appear to be possible without actually adding several category template files (unless you custom program it). I run Wordpress, and I have only seen it accomplished category by category.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates