# Making Categories Use Parent Template

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been stumbling over this for hours now. I need to do exactly what is being discussed here: [Make *ALL* Wordpress Categories use their Parent Category Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119961/make-all-wordpress-categories-use-their-parent-category-template)

I have a custom post type: "Research" and custom taxonomy "Classifications"

Under Classifications I have hierarchial "categories" as follows

```
Old Research
 subcat1
 subcat2
```

I have a working template file "taxonomy-Classifications-oldresearch.php" for the Old Research archive. However, the child categories are not using this and revert to "taxonomy-Classifications.php".

I would like all child categories to use the same template as the parent "old research", but I can't make the code in the link above work.

Comment: You have to show exactly what is not working for you and why this Question is not a duplicate of that one. DeadMedic's Answer is perfect. Use `var_dump($whatever);die();` to debug your code.

Comment: I coped and pasted samples of code from the post linked above and could not get any of it to work.

Like I said... these "categories or taxonomies" are in a custom post type of "Research" if it makes any difference.

Can anyone shed some light? Please highlight the elements in the code snippet where I need to change the text to fit. I would appreciate any help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

make use of the wordpress conditional comments and just filter, if it's in the same category use the template. You could do it 100 ways from sunday so just put in some directional logic in one of your higher up templates like classifications.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags