# Wordpress - custom template page for a parent category and all child categories

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In WP 5.4.2 I want to create a custom archive page for a category and all it's child categories. I am aware of the template file hierarchy:

```
1. category-slug.php
2. category-ID.php
3. category.php
4. archive.php
5. index.php
```

but if I understand correctly and if I did all the testing right, the `category-slug.php`, or the `category-id.php` scheme applies to a single category regardless of the category hierarchy.

Let's say I have following categories:

```
colors (id 2)
- red  (id 10)
- green (id 11)
- blue  (id 12)
```

I need a single template file for all of them. Simply creating `category-colors.php` or `category-2.php` doesn't work. It applies to the single category (colors) only. I want it to apply to all the current child categories, as well as all the child categories I add in the future. Is it possible? If so, please advice how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, but using the `category_template` filter to let you use a custom category template seems the most common.

The function below will let you dynamically check back through the parent levels of the current category until it finds a template called "category-*[parent slug]*" for the closest ancestor category or it reaches the top level - whichever is first.

Suppose you have something like:

```
 - products
    - hardware
    - food
      - dairy
      - vegetables
```

1. On the dairy page, it will first check if you have a slug called `category-dairy.php`.
2. If you do, it will return it.
3. If you don't, it will look for `category-food.php`.
4. If that's not found, it will look for `category-products.php`.

Add this to your functions.php - this is untested by the code is well commented so you can understand how it works:

```
function get_template_for_category( $template ) {

    if ( basename( $template ) === 'category.php' ) { // No custom template for this specific term, let's find it's parent
        // get the current term, e.g. red
        $term = get_queried_object();

        // check for template file for the page category
        $slug_template = locate_template( "category-{$term->slug}.php" );
        if ( $slug_template ) return $slug_template;

        // if the page category doesn't have a template, then start checking back through the parent levels to find a template for a parent slug
        $term_to_check = $term;
        while ( $term_to_check ->parent ) {
            // get the parent of the this level's parent
            $term_to_check = get_category( $term_to_check->parent );

            if ( ! $term_to_check || is_wp_error( $term_to_check ) )
                break; // No valid parent found

            // Use locate_template to check if a template exists for this categories slug
            $slug_template = locate_template( "category-{$term_to_check->slug}.php" );
            // if we find a template then return it. Otherwise the loop will check for this level's parent
            if ( $slug_template ) return $slug_template;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'category_template', 'get_template_for_category' );
```

References:

- [WP Codex `category_template` Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/category_template)
- [WP Developer `locate_template` Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/)
- [Make categories use parent template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119961/make-all-wordpress-categories-use-their-parent-category-template)

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand how is the parameter `$template` supposed to be filled and when I tested it, it was empty all the time. So I used this: `$template = get_archive_template();` inside the function and it works. I only had to change the check for `category.php` to `archive.php` since I don't use `category.php` at all

Comment: The reason $template is empty is because this filter is for category.php, so if you’re not using it then it would be empty. Glad you got it working!